# subscribing to a service in constructor is executing after ngOnInit in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

As we know, constructor executes first.. but when I'm trying to subscribes to a service in constructor, that is executing after the ngOnInit.. But I want to subscribe to the service before executing ngOnInt. Can you please help me?

This is my sample code

```
constructor(private otherRoleService: OtherRoleService) {
      this.data = [{
                    "roleid" : "0"
                  }]; 
this.otherRoleService.getOtherRoles(this.data).subscribe(res => console.log('constructor'), err => this.fail(err));}

ngOnInit(){
 console.log('OnInit')
}
```

Comment: You need to understand asynchronism. You're subscribing before ngOnInit. But you're receiving the first asynchronous event from your subscription  later. Just like, if you subscribe to a newsletter and then eat a toast, your toast will be eaten before you get the first mail from the newsletter, maybe a day or two later.

Comment: @JBNizet Doesn't that depend on the size of the toast? I mean if you have a toast made out of a full size bread, it could take a while to eat it

Comment: There is a good video about event loop, that will help you to understand how javascript works and why you get your data in subscription after onInit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 0):

You're subscribing to an event, and you're doing it at the correct time, the only thing is that the event is being fired after some time.

If you're using the angular router, you can check the [resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) feature, this will ensure that your observable will be resolved before to load your component